# Read from CellSet using LINQ

Tags: linq, ssas, mdx, adomd.net

```
AdomdCommand cmd = new AdomdCommand(commandText, conn);
CellSet cs = cmd.ExecuteCellSet();

var result = from a in cs
             select new
             {...};
```

Is it possible to use LINQ to read from CellSet? I have tried using DataTable instead of CellSet but it's much slower (Example: I took a query that using DataTable takes ~45 sec to execute, but using CellSet it takes ~5 sec).

The error I get when trying to use LINQ:

> Could not find an implementation of the query pattern for source type
>   'Microsoft.AnalysisServices.AdomdClient.CellSet'.  'Select' not found.

**UPDATE**:

I have tried Enrico's suggestion and so far it doesn't return any errors. Next problem is how to read a value from a cell. Here's what I have tried so far:

```
var result = from cell in cs.Cells.Cast<Cell>()
     select new searchResultsPolicy
     {
         PolicyNumber = ...
         InsuredName = cell.Field<string>("[Insured].[DBA Name].[DBA Name].[MEMBER_CAPTION]"),
         Agency = cell.Field<string>("[Agency].[Agency Name].[Agency Name].[MEMBER_CAPTION]"),
         Market = cell.Field<string>("[Market].[Market Name].[Market Name].[MEMBER_CAPTION]"),             
         Revenue = String.Format("{0:#,##0}", cell.Field<double?>("[Measures].[Revenue]") ?? 0),
         Premium = String.Format("{0:#,##0}", cell.Field<double?>("[Measures].[Premium]") ?? 0)
     };
```

Answer (score 2):

The reason you get that error is that the [CellSet](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.analysisservices.adomdclient.cellset.aspx) class in itself doesn't implement [IEnumerable<T>](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9eekhta0.aspx), which is required by LINQ.

Try executing the LINQ query over the [CellSet.Cells](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.analysisservices.adomdclient.cellset.cells.aspx) property instead. That will return a [CellCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.analysisservices.adomdclient.cellcollection.aspx) object, which implements [IEnumerable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.ienumerable.aspx). From there you can easily convert it to an [IEnumerable<T>](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9eekhta0.aspx) by using the [Enumerable.Cast<T>](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb341406.aspx) method.

```
AdomdCommand cmd = new AdomdCommand(commandText, conn);
CellSet cs = cmd.ExecuteCellSet();

var result = from cell in cs.Cells.Cast<Cell>()
             select new
             { ... };
```

**See also:**

- [Retrieving Data Using the CellSet](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms123476.aspx)

Comment: So far it doesn't return an error. Could you please give me a hint how to read a column value from cell in select new...? I have updated my question. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @ile What types are the `mngmOff` and `fn` variables?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to change the name of that variable. Instead of mngmOff it was suppose to be cell. I have fixed that now. And you can ignore fn too, it was just a name of a function that was used to format string.